# html input element still using "disabled" style, after remove "disabled" attribute via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several inputs element. When the page load, I disabled the input. Then when the user click edit, remove the `disabled` attribute so the user can edit it. But when the edit button is pressed and the `disabled` is removed, the input style still using disabled input style.
How can I fix this?

js:

```
document.querySelector('#enable-update').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var i;
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#manage-data input');
    for (i=0; i < inputs.length ; i++){
        inputs[i].disabled = false;
    }
    inputs[0].focus();

    var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('#manage-data textarea');
    for (i=0; i < textareas.length ; i++){
        textareas[i].disabled = false;
    }

    this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

html:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input disabled class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="name" name="name" value="user">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Nama</label>
</div>
```

PS : I'm using Material Lite Design

---

### **Update**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7dk5owg/1/)
(*I edit some syntax on the js file)

what I want to achieve is make this 
[image: disabled style]

to this (notice the "name" text is blue)
[image: non disabled style]

when i check the inspect element, it show this (notice the "fieldset[disabled]" but the input don't have disabled attribute) 
[image: inspect element still disabled style]

Comment: `ID` attributes specified in `JS` are not there in Markup..

Comment: this behavior is due to the scope behavior of the 'var i'

Comment: @IshankDubey – I do not think so...

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/9ogndbc9/

Comment: @Rayon u r right, i took that id must be somewhere in parent hierarchy.

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7dk5owg/)

actually, I made some change. And I just realize that this behaviour is happen when the input set to disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with the fixed version of your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/5kpqsc9t/4/

Your first problem is that you were selecting inputs inside #manage-data, but didn't add that ID to the wrapping div.

Your second problem was the inputs[0].focus(); outside the for loop.

There is no need for var i; when you declare it inside the for loop.

```
document.querySelector('#enable-update').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#manage-data input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length ; i++){
        inputs[i].disabled = false;

        inputs[i].focus();
    }
    this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label" id="manage-data">
    <input disabled class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="name" name="name" value="user">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Nama</label>
</div>

<button id="enable-update">
Enable
</button>
```

**Answer to edit**

The color that you think means it's disabled is the color that material design makes input fields. In the 'Elements' section in chrome, you can see that:

```
fieldset[disabled] .mdl-textfield .mdl-textfield__input
```

Is a light grey, being that's not what is being targeted.

What is being targeted is:

```
.mdl-textfield.is-disabled .mdl-textfield__input
```

Comment: aaahh, I just realise that. I think I too focus on `[disabled]` one. Thanks.

[solved filddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7dk5owg/4/)